# How to review and filter response in Grails after action is processed?

Tags: ajax, json, grails, groovy

I'm trying to alter JSON responses in my Grails 1.3.7 application using filters, but they're not working the way I expect. What I would like to do is use something like `render myobject as JSON` in my action and then in the filter do something like this:

```
jsonPostProcess(controller:'json', action:'*') {
    after = {
        if (myCustomLogicHere) {
            return false // render empty string
        } else if (more logic) {
            // write something else to the response
        }
    }
}
```

What actually happens is the response is sent back before the `after` block is executed. The same goes for `afterView`.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do the Grails way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JonoB answer is almost right:

Return myobject from the controller, then call render from the filter, e.g.:

```
class JsonController {
    someAction = {
         //...some logic
         return [myobject: myobject]
    }
}
```

and in filter

```
jsonPostProcess(controller:'json', action:'*') {
    after = {
        Map model ->
            //... my custom logic here
            render model.myobject as JSON
            return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Return `myobject` from the controller, then call `render` from the filter, e.g.:

```
class JsonController {

    someAction = {

        ...
        myobject
    }
}
```

and

```
jsonPostProcess(controller:'json', action:'*') {
    after = {

        myobject ->

        if (myCustomLogicHere) {
            return false // render empty string
        } else if (more logic) {
            // write something else to the response
        }

        render myobject as JSON
    }
}
```

Comment: Having suggested this, I'm not sure there's not something else going on, as the filter *should* be called before the view is rendered (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#filterTypes)

Comment: With Grails 1.3.7 I can't seem to get your example to work. I'm returning `[a:'b',c:'d']` from my action. In the filter I get the map as `myobject`, but when I try to render it as JSON I get a 404. Thanks for the answer, though. I'll mod up.